# Using Conditional Probability to Express a Single Event

Tags: probability

Can we make the statement:

$$P(A)=P(A|B)P(B) + P(A|B^c)P(B^c)$$

Using  Bayes Theorem:

$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(AB)}{P(B)}$$

so

$$P(A|B)P(B)+P(A|B^c)P(B^c)=P(AB)+P(AB^c)=P(A) $$

is this a valid line of proof?

Of course we have to assume that $0<P(B)<1$ ?

Comment: Can you clarify what it is you are trying to derive/prove?

Comment: This technique is sometimes referred to as partitioning an event. This is perfectly valid.

Comment: @SplitInfinity all I wanted to know is if I can exploit the first condition. It is for an assignment question so I would rather not post the actual thing I am trying to derive as this would be a breach of Academic Policy

Comment: @HughEntwistle Oh, my apologies. Yes, you can. It's called the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).

Comment: Sometimes called Bayes formula.

Comment: And yes, as you wrote you have to assume $0 <P(E)<1$ otherwise the conditional probabilities are not defined.